# Solutions of $x^n=a$ modulo primes.

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

Let $p$ be an odd prime and $a$ be an integer that is not a perfect square. We can impose a congruence condition on $p$ that guarantees the equation $x^2=a \pmod p$ does not have a solution. For example, if $a=5$, then the condition $p \equiv 2 \pmod 5$ implies that 5 is a quadratic nonresidue modulo $p$. Similarly, one can impose a congruence condition on $p$ that guarantees a solution exists. Can this be generalized for other exponents. In other words:

**Question 1:** *For what values of $n$ the following is true? Given any integer $a$ that is not the $n$th power of any integer, there exist integers $b,t$, such that for any prime $p$ with $p \equiv b \pmod t$ the equation $x^n \equiv a \pmod p$ **does not have** a solution.*

**Question 2:** *For what values of $n$ the following is true? Given any integer $a$, there exist integers $b,t$, such that for any prime $p$ with $p \equiv b \pmod t$ the equation $x^n \equiv a \pmod p$ **has** a solution.*

Comment: what has been tried ? cubes are only 0,1 or 6 mod 7 for example. Fifth powers are only 0,1,10 mod 11.

Comment: @RoddyMacPhee The case $n=2$ as I mentioned is clearly known. Other known cases include $n=4$ and $a=-1$ for example: If $p\equiv 1 \pmod 8$ then $x^4 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ has a solution, and if $p \not \equiv 1 \pmod 8$, then $x^4 \equiv -1 \pmod p$ has no solutions. I think the case $a=-1$ is completely know and there is a lot that can be said about $a=2$ as well.

Comment: Do you know Galois theory? Do you know about Frobenius elements? Do you know class field theory? To give a full answer to this question is fairly involved, and it might not be quite what you are looking for. A related (but different) question is for what $n$ is the number of solutions to $x^n \equiv a \bmod p$ determined by congruence conditions on $p$? And the answer to that is if and only if the Galois group of $x^n -a$ is abelian, which (for $a$ not a perfect power) only happens for $n = 1$ or $n = 2$.

Comment: @user687721I am kind of familiar with these topics. When you say the answer is fairly involved, do you mean the answer is known? Do you have any references?

Comment: I mean I can work it out myself. The problem is that there are a number of sub-cases for particular values of $a$ which require separate analysis and I'm not entirely sure I want to write it all down. Certainly the answer to Question 1 is "yes if $n$ is even and no if $n$ is odd." On the other hand the answer to Question 2 is yes for all $n$ for *most* values of $a$. However, certain $a$ cause problems and require some case analysis. For example, literally as stated, Question 2 has a negative answer when $6|n$ simply because of the case $a = -3$.

Comment: @user687721This is fascinating. So for example if $n=8$, we can impose a congruence relation on a prime to guarantee a given number $a$ is an $n$th power residue or not. Maybe you can also give me your insight on the following question: if $a$ is an integer that is not a perfect square and $0\leq i \leq 7$, then there exist $b,t$ such that if $p \equiv b \pmod t$ and $\eta$ is any primitive root modulo $p$, then $a \equiv \eta^s \pmod p$ where $s \equiv i \pmod 8$. Question 2 is when $i=0$.

Comment: Yes but the answer to question 2 is misleading, which is why I was trying to suggest that this formulation is a little strange. Let me explain the simplest case of question 2 which is when $n$ is odd. Then you simply choose a prime $p \equiv 2 \bmod n$. For such primes, the order of the multiplicative group $(\mathbf{Z}/p \mathbf{Z})^{\times}$ is $p-1$ which is prime to $n$, so *every* $a$ is then an $n$th power modulo $p$. So this gives a congruence condition to guarantee that $a$ is an $n$th power but only by finding a prime $p$ such that *everything* is an $n$th power.

Comment: The case when $n$ is even is harder because then $(n,p-1)$ is always divisible by $2$, but you can try to find primes with $(n,p-1) = 2$ and then add congruence conditions to ensure that $a$ is a square. This is almost always possible. For example, if you want $x^8 \equiv 5 \bmod p$ to have a solution, take $p \equiv -1 \bmod 20$. Then $(p-1,8) = 2$, so the $8$th powers modulo $p$ are exactly the squares modulo $p$. But also $p \equiv -1 \bmod 5$, which guarantees that $5$ is a square modulo $p$.

Comment: Your additional question: first insist that $p \equiv 3 \mod 4$. Then being of the form $\eta^s \bmod p$ for a class $s \bmod 8$ is just the same as being of the form $\eta^s \bmod p$ for a class $s \bmod 2$, because the $8$th powers are just the squares. So now you impose an additional congruence to ensure that $a$ is a quadratic residue or not modulo $p$. You can always do this unless $-a$ is a square.

Comment: In question 1 you have written "integer $a$ that is not the $n$th power of any integer". Note that $16$ is a perfect $8$th power modulo $p$ for all primes $p$ (which follows by factoring $x^8 - 16$ with Sophie-Germain). You might want to reformulate the condition to read "let $a$ be an integer such that for infinitely many primes $p$, the equation $x^n \equiv a \pmod{p}$ does not have a solution".

Comment: I read question one as integer $a$ that is not a perfect power (i.e. not the $m$th power of any integer for some $m > 1$, not necessarily $m = n$, and so in particular not a square).